# SQL Server SELECT from non-indexed view which references an indexed table

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, indexing, ssrs-2008

If I am selecting from a view which is non-indexed, and the view is selecting from an indexed table, will sql server use the index or do i have to index the view.

Comment: Probably but the only way to know is to look at the execution plan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server will use the index if it decides that will help the query time. There is no need to create *indexed* views simply to get your table indexes to work within a view!

Rather, indexed views allow you to create indexes on derived (and non-derived) data, which can offer huge performance increases in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

It will yes, when you do select from a simple view (non persistent), SQL server uses the view's query to create the plan.

So if you have a view like this:

```
create view1 as
select ID, name from table1
```

and you do:

```
select ID, name from view1
```

internally, its exactly the same as doing

```
select ID, name from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I am selecting from a view which is non-indexed, and the view is selecting from an indexed 
>   table,

Thsi is impossible.

See, view is not indexed A normal one does not even exist -it is a macro being expanded upon execution. So at the end you query from an indexed table.

UNless you materialize the view (totally diffferent advanced topic) the view is relly jsut a short cut.

Comment: SQL Server does have 'indexed views', a similar to oracle's materialized views.

Comment: FWIW [Indexed View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) is the correct terminology for SQL Server. Materialized View would be the Oracle terminology

Comment: +1 because this is a correct: a view expands like a macro (as [I keep saying](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a27535%20%2bview%20%2bmacro)) and the underlying tables are considered. The optimiser doesn't consider the view as an entity by itself.

Answer (score -1):

If I recall correctly, it will use the index to create the view but queries against the view don't use the index.   There are a whole host of considerations when talking about indexes on views though.

take a look at this link for all the ins and outs of sql server indexed views

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148(v=sql.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least add a comment so I understand why.  As far as I know nothing in my answer was incorrect and the op does need to consider a host of things when adding an index to a view in sql server.

Comment: If the index exists on the base table, queries against the view will use this index if the optimizer determines it is helpful. Here's a code sample to demonstrate: http://pastebin.com/Bcq9nHvX